# How to find all surjective functions $f:M_n(\Bbb R)\to\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$ satisfying $f(XY)\le\min{(f(X),f(Y))}$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $M_n(\Bbb R)$ be the set of all real $n\times n$ matrices. Find all surjective functions $f:M_n(\Bbb R)\to\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$ such that
$$f(XY)\le\min{(f(X),f(Y))}$$
for all $X,Y\in M_n(\Bbb R)$.

My try: since
$$f(XY)\le\min{(f(X),f(Y))}$$
so we have
$f(XY)\le f(X)$ and $f(XY)\le f(Y)$, but I can't proceed.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** $f(X)={\rm rank} X$, $~\forall X\in M_n(\Bbb R)$( $\Bbb R$ can be replaced with any field).

**Hint:**

1. Show that $f(I)=n$ by letting $Y=I$.
2. Show that if $X$ is invertible($~{\rm rank} X=n$), then $f(X)=n$ by letting $Y=X^{-1}$ and using 1.
3. Show that if $X$ and $Z$ are invertible, then $f(XYZ)=f(Y)$  by using 2.
4. Show that if ${\rm rank} X={\rm rank} Y$, then $f(X)=f(Y)$ by using 3.
5. Show that if ${\rm rank X}\le {\rm rank Y}$, then $f(X)\le f(Y)$ by using 4.
6. Make the conclusion from 4, 5 and the surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: can you post your full solution? Thank you

Comment: @chinamath: I was hoping you would complete the proof by yourself; if not, maybe it is better if you could tell me which step is unclear to you.